# Css carousel arrows flowing up on resize inside modal

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to create a carousel. But I'm having issues with chevrons on window resizing. They are starting to flow upwards, and hiding behind an image. And while `div.image-preview` might seem odd, I need it, since I might have video or other type of elements and I want to change inner div element depending on it's type.

This is what I have managed to done so far -

```css
.modal {
  display: block;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 20;
  padding-top: 150px;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: auto;
  background-color: rgb(0,0,0);
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.9);
}


.modal .full-media {
  position: fixed;
  left: 30%;
  /* bottom: 55%; */
  
} 

.modal .full-media .image-preview {
  padding-bottom: 0;
  margin-right: 6%;    
}

.modal .full-media .image-preview img {
  width: 700px;
  height: 700px;
}

i.next-slide {
  font-size: 54px;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  margin-left: 100px;
  float: left;
  margin-top: 15%;
}

i.prev-slide {
  font-size: 54px;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  margin-right: 100px;
  float: right;
  margin-top: 15%;
}

i:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.getmdl.io/1.1.3/material.indigo-pink.min.css">
<script defer src="https://code.getmdl.io/1.1.3/material.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="modal">
    <i class="material-icons next-slide" (click)="prevSlide()">chevron_left</i>
    <div class="full-media">
      <div class="image-preview">
        <img src="http://www.w3schools.com/howto/img_fjords.jpg" />
      </div>
    </div>
    <i class="material-icons prev-slide" (click)="nextSlide()">chevron_right</i>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

This is what I have at the moment -

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One nice solution is to make the arrow containers absolute, and adjust top, bottom, margin and height so that it centers vertically, like so:

```
i.next-slide {
  font-size: 54px;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 100px;
  margin: auto;
  height: 54px;
}

i.prev-slide {
  font-size: 54px;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 100px;
  margin: auto;
  height: 54px;
}
```

Notice that repeated properties could be specified in a common class.

```css
.modal {
  display: block;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 20;
  padding-top: 150px;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: auto;
  background-color: rgb(0,0,0);
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.9);
}


.modal .full-media {
  position: fixed;
  left: 30%;
  /* bottom: 55%; */
  
} 

.modal .full-media .image-preview {
  padding-bottom: 0;
  margin-right: 6%;    
}

.modal .full-media .image-preview img {
  width: 700px;
  height: 700px;
}
i.next-slide {
  font-size: 54px;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 100px;
  margin: auto;
  height: 54px;
}

i.prev-slide {
  font-size: 54px;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 100px;
  margin: auto;
  height: 54px;
}

i:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.getmdl.io/1.1.3/material.indigo-pink.min.css">
<script defer src="https://code.getmdl.io/1.1.3/material.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="modal">
    <i class="material-icons next-slide" (click)="prevSlide()">chevron_left</i>
    <div class="full-media">
      <div class="image-preview">
        <img src="http://www.w3schools.com/howto/img_fjords.jpg" />
      </div>
    </div>
    <i class="material-icons prev-slide" (click)="nextSlide()">chevron_right</i>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```